# if $\dot{x}<0$ and $\dot{|x|}<0$, what can we say about the convergence of $x$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

we have $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}<0$ and $\dot{|x|}=\frac{d|x|}{dt}<0$, that is: the derivative of $x$ is negative, the derivative of the absolute value of $x$ is negative, and $t$ is time. what can we say about the convergence of $x$? (which type of convergence? how to prove it?) thanks.

Comment: Do you mean convergence as $t\to\infty$?

Comment: yes, i mean the convergence about time

Comment: upvote, to make up for that uncommented and -- for me, incomprehensible -- downvote. Same for @ThomasAndrews answer.

Comment: Hah, I did the same for your answer, @Thomas :) Someone really did not like this question, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d|x|}{dt} = \operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac{dx}{dt}$$

So if $dx/dt<0$ and $d|x|/dt<0$ that means $x>0$.

So $x(t)$ is a decreasing but positive function, and therefore $$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\inf_{t\in\mathbb R} x(t)$$ exists.

Basically, you are using that a function which is bounded below has an infimum, and then the fact that $x$ is decreasing means that this infimum is the limit.

Comment: what's the condition to say that $\inf_{t\in\mathbb R} x(t)=0$?

Comment: There's no way, with derivatives, to say that the limit is $0$, since of it is true for $x=f(t)$ it is true for $x=f(t)+C$ for any positive constant $C$. Certainly, all we know here is that $\inf x(t)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$  \frac{d}{dt} |x |^  2 =2|x| \frac{d}{dt} |x | = 2x  \frac{d}{dt} x $$
so 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} |x | = \frac{x \frac{d}{dt}x}{|x|} < 0 $$
This implies $x>0$, due to the assumption on the derivative of $x$.  Since $x$ is decreasing and bounded from below, it has to converge to a value $x_0\ge 0$, if $ t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: what's the condition to say $x_0=0$?